# How to increase the size of the XFCE network contection popup?

Tags: xfce

I use Ubuntu 20.04 with `xfce4-panel 4.14.3 (Xfce 4.14)` and I cannot resize the networking connections pop up. It is too small and I always have to keep scrolling the double of its size.

[image]

I would not like to increase the font size, just the size of the popup, so I can see all of it at once, instead of keep scrolling on that small space.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this problem using a different theme, you can try default ones using `Aspect` and choosing a different theme, or you can download one on https://www.xfce-look.org/browse/ord/latest/

If this doesn't work I think it can be related to the system font, you can try to change the font, for example making it bigger, or using a different one.